# How does an app allow other devices to access my Wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration

I have bought a new Samsung TV.

When I turned it on, it asked me to install the app "SmartThings" on my smartphone in order to set it up.
That all worked well (probably over Bluetooth).

However, I was very surprised that afterwards the TV was also connected to my WiFi without me entering the WiFi-password or pressing a button on the router.

How is it technically possible that the app can allow other devices to connect to my WiFi?

Answer (score 0):

iOS has a special API, restricted by a special "entitlement" that is only given to apps that qualify for it, that allows apps that set up IoT devices to get the phone's current Wi-Fi network name and passphrase so the app can send that info to the device being configured. I presume Android has something similar.